# Cannot cast delegate to a generic type T

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Why can’t we cast an instance of a *delegate* to a generic type `T`?

Consider a utility method `CreateDelegate` that creates an instance of T, which is a *delegate*, i.e. a type derived from `MulticastDelegate`.

```
 T CreateDelegate<T>() {… }
```

**Unfortunately generics does not allow to constraint `T` to a type derived from `MulticastDelegate`** giving the following compilation error:

> Constraint cannot be special class 'System.MulticastDelegate'

Nevertheless, this utility method is checking that `T` is compatible with `MulticastDelegate` and creating a delegate via Reflection through `Delegate::CreateDelegate`. But, if we try to cast the result of `Delegate::CreateDelegate` to `T`, we will get the following compilation error:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Delegate' to 'T'

However, if I cast it first to `object` and then to `T` it will work fine:

```
T h = (T) ((object) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(T), target, m));
```

Why can’t we directly cast delegate to T?

Comment: does this works : ``T h =  Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(T), target, m) as T;`` ?

Comment: Yes, that works. And, it makes even less sense. IMHO the behavior of both operators (`as` and _cast_) should be consistent.

Comment: this way is more safe than casting object then from object to T, it will give you null if cast fails

Comment: Sometimes throwing an `Exception` is the desired behavior, instead of returning `null`.

Comment: yes abosultley right

Comment: There are Eric Lippert posts on this topic. If you are interested in language design, C# in particular, read all of Erics blog.

Comment: @usr An obviously good suggestion :-) Updated my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The C# language imposes a static check whether a cast from type X to type Y is valid — i.e. whether it makes *sense* in that the compiler can (to certain degree) guarantee compatibility and reject errors that as clear on compile-time. An unconstrained generic type `T` and `System.Delegate` have nothing directly in common. However, when casted to `object` the compiler knows that *every* type is esentially an `object`, so it allows the cast. That doesn't mean a run-time type check won't fail in a particular case.

The `as` operator is a little bit more permissive, as it won't cause an exception for an otherwise-invalid cast. The compiler is also less-strict in applying static checks. In your particular case this is helpful as you can omit the intermediate cast to `object` and use `as T`. However, one this required is that `as` works on class types only, so you have to apply the `where T : class` constraint.

So the method then would look like this (simplified):

```
public T CreateDelegate<T>(…) where T : class
{
    return Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(T), …) as T;
}
```

As @usr suggested, a recommended reading is Eric Lippert's blog, e.g. [this article on casts and type parameters](http://ericlippert.com/2015/10/14/casts-and-type-parameters-do-not-mix/).